# Tab Font Color Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to change the tab font color in excel? I am using excel 2011 and I have tried the following in VBA:

```
Sub SheetTabFontColor()      
Sheets("Sheet1").Tab.Font.Color = 255  
End Sub
```

The error reads:

Run-time error '438':
Object Does not Support this property or method

I'm wondering if there is some kind of work-around  that allows me to change the font color to something other than the automatic white/black.

Comment: Font colour is set by Excel itself, White on a dark tab colour, Black on a light tab colour  and this isn't user changeable.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I hoped there was some way around it. I wonder why it was designed to be unchangeable by the user. It's not very critical, but little aesthetics like this can add a nice touch of flair to an otherwise drab document. Thank you for your comment!